# Variable Scope Issue using Node.js with Recaptcha

Tags: node.js, recaptcha

I am using Recaptcha in Node.js and I am having some trouble with the scope of some boolean variables. Recaptcha will work if only I can figure this out. Also, I'm not using express.

If recaptcha was evaluated correctly, flag will be set to true in the function inside of simple_recaptcha. But when the function terminates, flag is false and is no longer true.

I am wondering if I can pass by reference to resolve this? Are there any other ways?

```
function processRecaptcha(response){
       ...got IP address ...
       ...set some variables ...
       flag = false; // I have tried both w/o var and with var

       simple_recaptcha(recaptcha_private_key, ip, challenge, response, function(err)    {
            if (err) {
               flag = false;
               console.log('recaptcha code: Incorrect. Flag is: ' + flag);
            }
            else{
               flag = true;
               console.log('recaptcha code: Correct. Flag is: ' + flag);
            }
      });
      console.log('Flag is: ' + flag);
      return flag;
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function is working as it should (most likely), and you have this problem due to async nature of the **simple_recaptcha** call.

Your code does this:

1. it sets the flag to false
2. it then starts some function which will receive the callback (the `simple_recaptcha()` function)
3. It then logs that the flag is false.

And sometimes later, when the simple_recaptcha is resolved, your flag is set to true. But the original function is by now returned.

Depending on your code and usage, you should be able to move the `return flag;` part somewhere inside the `simple_recaptcha()` callback function.